# Remove DC bias without phase shift?

Tags: amplifier, analog

Are there any circuits than can remove DC bias of an input signal without inducing a phase shift?

I'm thinking for the input of an amplifier but whatever will work.

Comment: You say "inducing a phase shift". A phase shift **with respect to what**? Do you really mean without adding any **delay**?

Comment: Do you know a priori how much DC offset you want to remove?  Is it fixed?  If not, at what rate can it change?  What is your band of interest?  What will the output be driving?

Comment: If trying to maintain phase congruency for audio signals, note that you *could* split the signal (and change your frame of reference.)  On one leg, introduce some static delay by offsetting DC, then delay the other signal to match.  Then *with respect to each other*, there is zero phase shift (but both are equally delayed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about eliminating the frequency-dependent phase shift caused by coupling capacitors in audio circuits, then - yes.

The problem is that even in a carefully tuned audio amplifier circuit with any appreciable gain, the DC operating point will drift with time and temperature.  The solution is called a DC servo.

Besides the output signal going wherever it goes, it also goes to a high-impedance integrator circuit.  This is basically a lowpass filter and algebraic averager, and the output is a DC level that represents the average DC level of the audio signal plus whatever drifting goes on in the main circuit.  The servo output signal is scaled, inverted, and summed into the audio signal at the amplifier input.  Because it is a high impedance network, the integrator can have a time constant of 1 second without requiring a large capacitor.

Search for something like 'audio amp dc servo schematic' to get sample schematics.  Here is a quickie grab off the innergoogle to show the concept.  R3-C4 set the integrator time constant, effectively equivalent to the cutoff frequency of the input and output coupling capacitors.  Given what this circuit is supposed to show, I'm not sure why Cin is there.

http://www.next.gr/circuits/DC-Servo-2-l38751.html

[image]

Answer (score 7):

> Are there any circuits than can remove DC bias of an input signal without inducing a phase shift?

Real life linear circuits, no. All real-world filters must be causal, that is output response occurs after the input signal, and that means phase shift. Even linear 'DC servoes' are just ways of building highpass filters with a very long time constant. The longer the time constant, the less the phase shift at operating frequency, but it's still finite. Even if you are observing a meter, and twiddling a potentiometer in response to zero out the output offset, you are part of the DC servo, and form part of the highpass filter. You can achieve the same phase shift by choosing the same time constant, whether using a conventional highpass filter, or a DC servo. There is a tradeoff between phase shift and settling time. If you choose a long time constant, then you'll have low phase shift, but a long settling time.

If we lose the linear constraint, then this is where a non-linear DC servo, or a human-in-the-loop, can improve that tradeoff. A human, observing the meter, could decide when the DC compensation was wrong, make a rapid adjustment, then leave the adjustments alone, after which there is no phase shift. That sort of behaviour is easy when you're a human, more or less impossible in an analogue circuit, and surprisingly tough to code into a processor-controlled loop so that it does what you want. Of course if it then drifts, you have to make another adjustment, and that upsets your signal.

If we lose the real-life or real-time constraint, and do offline processing of signals, then you have the ability to make filters acausal, ones which have a response before the input, which now permits you to get zero phase shift. The two easiest ways to implement them are to use a symmetrical FIR filter, or to run the same arbitrary filter both forwards and backwards over the time series. Both these filter routes guarantee zero phase shift.